# Issue with SSR with React and Spring boot java

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, webpack

We have a web application in which the backend is spring boot and front end is react. We are trying to integrate these applications in such a way that we can make use of spring boot jar file to run them both on the same port.

Following piece of java code is being used for integration.

```
@Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> htmlRouter(@Value("classpath:/static/index.html") Resource html) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(
                GET("/*"),
                request -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).bodyValue(html)
        );
    }
```

This is working fine when we create frontend build using react-scripts build. We want to make use of webpack build as there will be multiple such applications and they will be integrated using micro front-end which will work only when webpack is in place.
When trying do so the jar file is getting built. When we run this jar file and hit the url we get following error-

```
refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8765/abc/xyz' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Part of webpack config

```
output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    }
```

Following is the folder structure of the project

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using Spring's [script views](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc-view/mvc-script.html) for this purpose: if you think about that, in the end you need some type of engine for dealing with SSR. For React, the documentation suggest the use of Nashorn.

The documentation suggest a possible [configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc-view/mvc-script.html#mvc-view-script-integrate) for different scripting libraries:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.scriptTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    public ScriptTemplateConfigurer configurer() {
        ScriptTemplateConfigurer configurer = new ScriptTemplateConfigurer();
        configurer.setEngineName("nashorn");
        configurer.setScripts("mustache.js");
        configurer.setRenderObject("Mustache");
        configurer.setRenderFunction("render");
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

In the specific use case of React we can find different, more complete examples, for instance in [this Github repository](https://github.com/onready/spring-react-ssr/blob/master/src/main/java/com/onready/springreactssr/config/WebConfig.java):

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.script.ScriptTemplateConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry viewResolverRegistry) {
    viewResolverRegistry.scriptTemplate().prefix("/templates/").suffix(".html");
  }

  @Bean
  public ScriptTemplateConfigurer scriptTemplateConfigurer() {
    ScriptTemplateConfigurer scriptTemplateConfigurer = new ScriptTemplateConfigurer("nashorn");
    scriptTemplateConfigurer.setScripts("/js/polyfill.js", "/js/built/bundle-server.js");
    scriptTemplateConfigurer.setRenderFunction("render");
    scriptTemplateConfigurer.setSharedEngine(false);
    return scriptTemplateConfigurer;
  }

}
```

Or [this other one](https://github.com/davehancock/react-ssr-sample-java-nashorn/blob/master/src/main/java/com/djh/SSRConfiguration.java), dated, but I think still useful as well:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.script.ScriptTemplateConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.script.ScriptTemplateViewResolver;

/**
 * @author David Hancock
 */
@Configuration
public class SSRConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver reactViewResolver() {
        return new ScriptTemplateViewResolver("/public/", ".html");
    }

    @Bean
    public ScriptTemplateConfigurer reactConfigurer() {
        ScriptTemplateConfigurer configurer = new ScriptTemplateConfigurer();
        configurer.setEngineName("nashorn");
        configurer.setScripts(
                "public/nashorn-polyfill.js",
                "public/server.js"
        );
        configurer.setRenderFunction("render");
        configurer.setSharedEngine(false);
        return configurer;
    }

}
```

As you can see they look quite similar in the implementation: basically, you need to indicate the scripts that should be loaded by the script engine, one of course the `bundle` generated by `webpack`, and at least one more (see [this](https://github.com/onready/spring-react-ssr/blob/master/src/main/resources/js/polyfill.js) or [this other example](https://github.com/davehancock/react-ssr-sample-java-nashorn/blob/master/public/nashorn-polyfill.js)), a polyfill for supporting `window`, etc.

I came across [another good example](https://github.com/terwer/spring-vue-ssr/blob/master/src/main/java/com/terwergreen/vue/VueRenderer.java): it is for Vue, not for React, but even in that case it provides a good example of using the Nashorn engine for SSR.

As a follow-up of the comment provided by @walen, probably a much better solution than using Spring Boot and some type of script engine implemented in Java - nowadays deprecated - for serving the React content, is architecting your application in a different way, deploying independently your backend and your frontend. Then, use `NodeJS` actually run your React application, and optionally nginx, Apache, or other type of reverse proxy to serve everything, it is the normal way to proceed. You can use Docker (Kubernetes, etc) or some type of equivalent container infrastructure to deploy the solution as a whole. From a microservices point of view this different architecture is preferable.

Comment: Nashorn was deprecated in Java 11 (2018) and ultimately removed in Java 15 (2020).

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @walen, I appreciate it. Yes, I was aware of that, but the OP doesn't mention the JDK version that he is using and, as you can read in the answer, the current documentation of Spring nowadays still mentions it as the appropriate Javascript engine for this purpose: I think GraalVM is not suitable, at least in this context.

Comment: @walen It turns out that in fact GraalVM seems that can be used for this purpose as well, it is true than in a [different context of React](https://tangent-jotey.medium.com/svelte-ssr-but-its-java-spring-boot-6536d5226dea), and in a bit more elaborated way [1](https://github.com/tncrazvan/svelte-3-jssr-starter/tree/master) [2](https://github.com/tncrazvan/java-springboot-svelte3-ssr-template/issues/5#issuecomment-903292777).

Answer (score 0):

Your router is configured to handle all URLs and return an HTML page:

```java
return RouterFunctions.route(
    GET("/*"),
    request -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).bodyValue(html)
);
```

If your page contains a `<script src="...">` tag, the browser will fetch the URL to get the script.
The server will return an HTML page with the `text/html` content-type, which triggers the error message
because the browser expects `text/javascript` instead.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried such things nothing worked